# How to find the original matrix given its basis for column & null space?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I was given this problem:

> Find a matrix $A$ such that $C(A)$ is spanned by $(1, 2, -1, 3), (2, 1, 1, 1), (3, 1, -1 , 1)$ and $N(A)$ is spanned by $(-2, -1, 1, 0, 0), (-3, 2, 0, -2, 1)$.

I have no idea where to start with this. I know that the column space basis vectors must be in the original, $A$, but I have no clue how I would derive the remaining two dependent columns for the null space.

I also know that $A$ should be $4 \times 5$ with rank $3$, but what trips me up is where to place the independent columns in this matrix (a.k.a. the $C(A)$ basis vectors).

Thanks

Comment: Please edit your post to include the question (not a link to an image). I have dropped a few words to get you started. Also, you need to include things that you know that might be relevant. Have a look at this first: [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: As a starting point, what are the dimensions of the matrix? What is its rank? Which columns contain pivots?

Comment: @SammyBlack The matrix should be 4x5 with rank 3. I am unsure which columns contain pivots though.

Comment: If you were row reducing $A$ to determine its null space, what would this reduced matrix $B$ look like that would produce such a basis for $N(A) = N(B)$? Recall that in RREF, each pivot variable is expressed as linear combination of the free variables in columns to the right of it.

Comment: Also, have a look at [this tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format math using MathJax/LaTeX.

Comment: @SammyBlack I presume that the reduced matrix for $B$ would contain 3 pivot columns with just 1 (corresponding to rank 3) and then 2 other columns used to find the nullspace? I am unsure how these other 2 columns would look, or where these 3 pivot columns would be in $B$ though.

Comment: You're on the right track! What does it mean for each of those vectors to be in the null space?

Comment: @SammyBlack Ok I think I figured it out, albeit, in a pretty nonmathematical way I think, haha. So if we say that $A = (v_1, v_2, v_3, v_4, v_5)$, using the null space, we know that 1. $-2v_1 - v_2 + v_3 = 0$ and 2. $-3v_1 + 2v_2 - 2v_4 = 0$. We select $v_1$ and $v_2$ as the first two columns in the column space. $v_3$ now cannot be independently selected, we solve for it using the first equation. Then we select $v_4$ as the final column of the column space. $v_5$ now also cannot be indendently selected, we solve for it using the second equation. Is this a valid approach?

Comment: That's right. I'll write up a slightly different approach that is equivalent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think about the linear transformation $\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^m$ defined by $\mathbf{x} \mapsto A\mathbf{x}$. As you've observed, based on the size of the vectors in the column space and null space, $m = 4$ and $n = 5$. Moreover, since the column space is $3$-dimensional, the matrix has rank $3$, so it has $3$ pivot columns. Equivalently, since the null space is $2$-dimensional, the matrix has corank $2$, i.e., it has $2$ other columns corresponding to free variables.

We can determine $A$ explicitly in two steps, first using the null space then the column space.

##### Step 1: Null space

An arbitrary vector in the null space is a linear combination of the $2$ given null vectors, so it looks like
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
x_1 \\ x_2 \\ x_3 \\ x_4 \\ x_5
\end{pmatrix} 
= s\begin{pmatrix}
-2 \\ -1 \\ 1 \\ 0 \\ 0
\end{pmatrix} 
+ t\begin{pmatrix}
-3 \\ 2 \\ 0 \\ -2 \\ 1
\end{pmatrix}
= \begin{pmatrix}
-2s - 3t \\ -s + 2t \\ s \\ -2t \\ t
\end{pmatrix}
$$
This is equivalent to the system of equations
$$
\left\{
\begin{aligned}
x_1 &= -2s - 3t \\
x_2 &= -s + 2t \\
x_3 &= s \\
x_4 &= -2t \\
x_5 &= t
\end{aligned}
\right.
$$
so it makes sense to drop $s$ and $t$ and replace them by the free variables $x_3$ and $x_5$, respectively. So this system is equivalent to
$$
\left\{
\begin{aligned}
x_1 + 2x_3 + 3x_5 &= 0 \\
x_2 + x_3 - 2x_5 &= 0 \\
x_4 + 2x_5 &= 0 \\
\end{aligned}
\right.
$$
As a $4 \times 5$ matrix this relationship among the variables is represented by the matrix
$$
\begin{pmatrix} 
1 & 0 & 2 & 0 & 3 \\
0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & -2 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 2 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 
\end{pmatrix}, 
$$
which is the RREF of the matrix $A$ that you seek, since this is entirely determined by the relationship among the columns (the variables) and row operations do not affect this.

##### Step 2: Column space

As it stands, this matrix has the correct null space, but its image is not correct. Looking at the standard basis vectors in $\mathbb{R}^5$ corresponding to the pivot columns, we can see that
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 0
\end{pmatrix} 
\mapsto 
\begin{pmatrix}
1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 
\end{pmatrix},
\qquad 
\begin{pmatrix}
0 \\ 1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 0
\end{pmatrix} 
\mapsto 
\begin{pmatrix}
0 \\ 1 \\ 0 \\ 0 
\end{pmatrix},
\quad\text{and}\quad 
\begin{pmatrix}
0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 1 \\ 0
\end{pmatrix} 
\mapsto 
\begin{pmatrix}
0 \\ 0 \\ 1 \\ 0 
\end{pmatrix}. 
$$
However, we want these images to be the given basis vectors of the column space, so we just use those vectors to form a square matrix that acts on the left (row operations), reversing the process that led to the RREF in the first place. It doesn't matter what the fourth column is, just as long as the resulting transformation is still invertible.

Therefore, one possibility is
$$
A = \begin{pmatrix} 
1 & 2 & 3 & 0 \\
2 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
-1 & 1 & -1 & 0 \\ 
3 & 1 & 1 & 1  
\end{pmatrix} 
\begin{pmatrix} 
1 & 0 & 2 & 0 & 3 \\
0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & -2 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 2 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 
\end{pmatrix} 
= \begin{pmatrix} 
 1 & 2 &  4 &  3 &  5 \\
 2 & 1 &  5 &  1 &  6 \\
-1 & 1 & -1 & -1 & -7 \\ 
 3 & 1 &  7 &  1 &  9 
\end{pmatrix}. 
$$

Answer (score 1):

I like the solution provided by @Sammy Black. However, I would like to add a side note. The step of dropping $s$ and $t$ and replacing them by $x_3$ and $x_5$ is a nice one, but in general, it may not be the case that you can find such variables to do something similar. Here's a slightly more general approach to the first step:

Since you want the solutions of the equation $AX=0$ to be spanned by $(-2, -1, 1, 0, 0)$ and $(-3, 2, 0, -2, 1)$, then each row of $A$ must be orthogonal to both vectors. This condition is satisfied for every vector $Y$ such that
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
-2 & -1 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
-3 & 2 & 0 & -2 & 1
\end{pmatrix} Y = \mathbf{0}.
$$
You can use then row reduction to find a basis for the solutions of the previous system, for example, $\left\lbrace (1, 0, 2, 0, 3), (0, 1, 1, 0, -2), (0, 0, 0, 1, 2) \right\rbrace$, which are the same vectors for the rows than the ones found by @Sammy Black.

This last step can be easily generalized, since it's just row reduction of the matrix whose rows are the ones that span $\mathcal{N}(A)$.

Comment: Yes! This is a nice generalization. The technique I illustrated works when we have a basis for the null space consisting of vectors of this particular form: the last nonzero entry is $1$, ordered in such a way that subsequent basis vectors have $0$ in that same entry. (This is what we always obtain from the standard Gaussian elimination algorithm.)